# Is HTTP Origin header reliable?

Tags: http, cors

We can change the Origin header in AJAX request or using the Chrome's plugin 'Modify Headers'. 
Therefore we can access data from the another host.
So is it reliable approach to handle CORS ?

Comment: Define _"reliable approach to handle CORS"_. Do you want to use CORS headers as a way of authentication? Then don't.

Comment: I want to restrict to use my Host (server) only from my Origin.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
And ask is there a way to fake it.

Comment: CORS is meant to protect the user (client/browser) from a CSRF attack, by making sure the target server knows that the request has been made from a different host

Answer (score 3):

HTTP_ORIGIN is neither sent by all browsers nor is it secure.

Nothing sent by the browser can ever be considered safe.

HTTP is a plain-text protocol. The ENTIRE request header/body structure can be faked to say anything you want.